# How to troubleshoot a crashing iOS app -- nonsensical crash logs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

we have installed (via Xcode) an app on an iPad mini (iOS 7.1.2), and it has started crashing immediately (you see a black screen briefly, then crash to home page).

Before we reinstall, we'd like to troubleshoot.  I've consulted apple doc about crash logs, but I can't correlate what I see in the device logs with anything they're talking about.

We connect the device, open Xcode (Version 6.4) and go to Window>Devices.  Navigate to our device (verify our app listed under "Installed Apps"), click on "Device Logs".  What we see is here:

[image: Confusing device log]

Unknown process, unknown type, very frequent, and the identifying text is "power assertion timeout for "com.apple.timed.ntp" which I don't think has to do with our App.  Furthermore, when I make the crash happen, and then repeat the process above, I do *not* see a new record corresponding to our crash.  Also the search doesn't seem to turn up anything related to our app/project.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Am I looking in the wrong place?  Does our crash reporting seem broken?  Is there anything else I should be doing to diagnose our insta-crash?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would try two things: - try sorting by process (your screenshot sorts by Date), - try looking at "All Logs" and see if you find it. Unknown/Unknown are the Apple apps and Services. You can also look at the logs on the device Settings->General->About->Diagnostics and Usage->Diagnostics and usage data.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's funny, I don't see anything related to my app when I do those things.  But your answer gives me confidence I'm looking in the right place, thanks.  I guess I should I conclude then that it's not "crashing" from the OS perspective?  I guess I'll go back into development mode with Xcode (and possibly lose a troubleshooting opportunity if the problem goes away) and see if I can find a logic error.

Comment: Um, are you using Core Data? Also, in the source code are there any calls to "abort()" or NSAsserts?. both of those would make the app stop without generating a crash report. The NSAsserts would crash only when running while attached to Xcode.

Comment: To tell you the truth I'm not sure if it's using core data... I inherited it but I'll take a look for that.  Definitely no abort or NSAsserts in there.  Why would core data crash silently? seems like an internal data interface would be conducive to throwing exceptions, etc.

Comment: The Core Data templates have some calls to `abort()` in them. People don't always remove them. A call to `abort()` will silently crash an app.